# Column in table sorted by default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

Have a table that can sort each column in the table working fine. I was wondering how the table decides what to sort by by default. I think currently it is sorting by the first column (which kind of makes sense) but i'd prefer it to sort by something else as a default. I want it to sort by time, most recent time on top, and when I call the same sort method I have to sort the column when a user clicks on them it won't work the same. I have [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2G9WyMPlVZV4J06xNXRo?p=preview) here.

The method I have to order the columns based on which one is clicked is

```
  $scope.order = function(predicate, reverse) {
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    $scope.recentalerts = orderBy($scope.recentalerts, predicate, $scope.reverse);
  };
```

and I am just trying to use the same call I use in the html to sort by default on the time column:

```
$scope.order('-time');
```

but when i load up the plunker nothing happens as I expected it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## original solution

You were calling your `order` function before you received the data from your call.  Simply move your method call to the `success` callback on your promise.

```
  $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4djr5').success(function(data) {
      $scope.recentalerts = data;
      $scope.total = $scope.recentalerts.length;

      $scope.order('-time')
  });
```

updated plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/uFJ8CtHYK99Nv3A6VsXO?p=preview

## better solution

Here is a more *angular* way of doing it.  This negates the need to manually handle the sort once you fetch your data.  And it leverages your existing `ng-click` as well as angular's `$digest` cycle.

**orderBy declaration**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="alert in recentalerts | orderBy:sortAttr:reverse">
```

**order func**

```
$scope.order = function(predicate) {
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    $scope.sortAttr = pedicate
  };
```

And as an added benefit you are not affected the original array, much like the relationship between a collection and it's source array.

plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/5iA40dqxBT96kA6qHZD3?p=preview

Comment: Oh, so you just placed the `$scope.order('time')` call inside of the `$http.get()`. lol that is literally the only place I didn't try to place it. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

I've forked your plunker - please check it out.
http://plnkr.co/edit/G3qAeHBq5tmbJCZlsgkA?p=preview

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter',
    function($scope, $http, $filter) {

      var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
      $scope.order = function(predicate) {
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
        $scope.recentalerts = orderBy($scope.recentalerts, predicate, $scope.reverse);
      };

      $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4djr5').success(function(data) {
        $scope.recentalerts = data;
             $scope.order('time');
        $scope.total = $scope.recentalerts.length;
      });


      $scope.reverse = true;

    }
  ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I said to @jusopi that is like the only place I didn't try. Thanks for the response